# i meet with some problems in java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a matrix and one more column shows up on the rightmost side.
The value of that column is same as the first row and first column.
Are there any problems in my code? I'm not very familiar with Java.

```
import java.util.*;
class Test
{
public static Scanner br = new Scanner(System.in);
static int w [][];
static int n;
static int i, j;

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Find the shortest edge");
    System.out.println("\nEnter the number of the vertices: ");
    n = br.nextInt();
    w = new int[n+1][n+1];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if((i!=j))
            {
            w[i][j] = w[j][i]= 1+(int)(Math.random()*9);
            }
            else if(i == j)
            {
                w[i][j] = w[j][i] = 0;
            }
        }
    Graph();
    Prim();
}

static void Graph()
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            System.out.print("  "+w[i][j]+"  ");
        }
    System.out.println(w[i][j]+"  ");
    }
}
static void Prim()
{
    getMinlength();
}
static void getMinlength()
{
    int a=1,b=2;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            if((w[i][j] < w[a][b])&&(i!=j))
            {
                a=i;
                b=j;
            }
        }
    System.out.println("The shortest edge is "+a+" to "+b);
}
}
```

Comment: Yes. One problem in your code is the lack of consistent indentation.

Comment: And the horrid habit of putting { on new line. Makes it hard to read.

Comment: @MightyPork Harder to read... a little bit like numbers in text to represent words? And your point is subjective, although I am a fan of K&R in general.

Comment: @MightyPork No offense, but the same can be said of your choice to substitute the number "2" for the English word "to"...which it looks like you've edited out now :)

Comment: And not putting any braces around the outer for-loop

Comment: @PrakashK furthermorei want to chat with u for my assignment~ can i add your facebook or any other APPS?

Comment: yes you can send me a msg on facebook

Comment: @PrakashK  oooops what is your name?

Comment: you can find out from my SO profile :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must replace the last line in Graph() method
from:

`System.out.println(w[i][j]+"  ");`

to:

`System.out.println();`

Comment: and can i ask some furthermore? whats your facebook or any other APPs to chat with u?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the outer loop of your Graph function.
You just want to print a new line, not another value w[i][j]

e.g.

```
System.out.println("");
```

Comment: i have some more questions of my assignment...can i add your facebook or any other APPS to chat with you?